# Recreating scriptApproval.xml hashcodes

Tags: jenkins

I'm attempting to recreate a scriptApproval.xml from scratch, to recreate a Jenkins instance from code. However, I have not been able to figure out how to create the hashes in the file:

```
  <approvedScriptHashes>
    <string>017[...]</string>
  </approvedScriptHashes>
```

I tried comparing files from separate instances, but the hashes don't match, and I need to be able to cherry pick the approved scripts since I need to be able to recreate this file by hand for automation purposes.